# What is the estimate for total number of flight hours in the world?

Tags: flight-data-monitoring, statistics

Working on a type of estimate model for aviation and was wondering if there was an approximate total number of flight hours in a year across the industry as a whole?

Edit: Counting only Commercial Flights

Comment: AOPA says "The latest data shows general aviation flies more than 20 million hours each year". I think may just be in the US.  That includes me and my 50 hours.  They have a nice 2 page brochure on What is General Aviation? 
https://www.aopa.org/-/media/files/aopa/home/advocacy/what_ga.pdf  Then you have all the commercial passenger flights, adding millions more ...

Comment: Are you including GA and military?

Comment: @ManuH just commercial Aviation, apologies for the lack of specification.

Comment: @PatrickMcClean no worry, that's also why comment are for (giving help to precise the question)

Answer (score 4):

In 2018 there were about [37.8 million commercial flights](https://news.aviation-safety.net/2019/01/01/aviation-safety-network-releases-2018-airliner-accident-statistics/). If we multiply this number with the overall average flight duration, we get the answer. Unfortunately I could not find a result for this directly.

We can however calculate it from the data provided by the [MIT Airline Data Project](http://web.mit.edu/airlinedata/www/Aircraft&Related.html). The data says there were [3,954 aircraft](http://web.mit.edu/airlinedata/www/2018%2012%20Month%20Documents/Aircraft%20and%20Related/Total%20Fleet/Total%20Operating%20Fleet.htm) available on average in 2018 that accumulated a combined [13,398,545 flight hours](http://web.mit.edu/airlinedata/www/2018%2012%20Month%20Documents/Aircraft%20and%20Related/Total%20Fleet/Total%20Aircraft%20Airborne%20Hours%20-%20ALL%20AIRCRAFT.htm) with [3.82 departures](http://web.mit.edu/airlinedata/www/2018%2012%20Month%20Documents/Aircraft%20and%20Related/Total%20Fleet/Departure%20per%20Aircraft%20Day%20-%20ALL%20AIRCRAFT.htm) per aircraft per day on average. This means the average flight duration was

$$ d = \frac{13\,398\,545 \, \mathrm{h}}{3954 \times 365 \times 3.82} \approx 2.43 \, \mathrm{h} $$

This is just based on various US carriers, so the world average might be somewhat different, but since US carriers fly a wide variety of flights from short domestic routes to ultra-long haul international routes, I assume this number to be close to the true answer.

The resulting total number of flight hours is then

$$ 37.8 \cdot 10^{6} \times d \approx \mathbf{91.8 \cdot 10^6 \, h} $$

*This does not yet include GA traffic or military flights.*

Comment: Great answer to a tough question, giving estimates (supported by sources) and resulting in a useful approximation (i.e. 91.8 x 10^6 h; or in words: a tad shy of 100 million hours per year)